# Initialize Firebase Analytics after Opt-In

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-analytics, next.js

I am trying to use Firebase´s Google Analytics for my Nextjs App.

Problem is i live in Germany and i am only allowed to use Analytics after user Opt-in.

My Config looks like that:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";

const firebaseConfig = {
  //my Config
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);
```

I have a Cookie Consent Component where the user can Accept or Decline the use of Cookies. On Accept i want to initialize Firebase analytics. Is it possible to export the analytics and initialize it in the Cookie Consent Component after the user Input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am kind of getting swamped by this topic too. Perhaps you could initialize with `const analytics = getAnalytics(app).setAnalyticsCollectionEnabled(false);` and then set it true on accept.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This still helped me out a lot, even though i struggled with this 5 months ago

Answer (score 0):

I have this function inside my firebase file and call it when users click on "accept". Works great

```
export function setCookies() {
  if (app.name && typeof window !== 'undefined') {
    const analytics = getAnalytics(app)
  }
}
```

Comment: What happens to the analytics variable? Don't you need to export it in order to start tracking events?